# UK Visa form filling

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

In these fields, how can put ( N/A or Empty field or Depends On husband or Father) in my wife and six year old child application those depend on me. I will spend all our expenses in travelling. My wife and child don't earn and don't spend expense at home. Because I give her.

Please let me know solution. [image][image]

Answer (score 4):

The visa application also has a space to indicate that someone else is paying for the cost of your trip. The forms for your wife and child should indicate that you are paying for the cost of the trip. They can answer zero to the questions about how much they are personally spending, and also their income and expenses (assuming they actually have no income). You should include the expenses for them in the question about the amount you are paying, and also the question about money you spend supporting them in your regular expenses. You should note on the applications that you are traveling together.